# Polymerfire - Read document once

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymerfire

I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve a document just once, and avoid every kind of bidirectional sync with the database.

The Polymerfire documentation is poor, and I couldn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the `firebase-document` element does not have a `'once'` mode. However, you can easily drop down to the underlying JS SDK if you've already initialized the SDK with `firebase-app`:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  attached: function() {
    firebase.database().ref('/path/to/doc')
      .once('value').then(snap => this.data = snap.val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution. You can check if the data are already loaded and then call the off() method on firebase reference, which disables all listeners.

Here are the important parts of code:

```
<firebase-document id="office_document" app-name="doctor-appointment-system" path="/offices/{{profileID}}" data="{{officeData}}">
</firebase-document>


        dataNotLoaded: {
            type: Boolean,
            computed: 'computeDataAvailability(officeData)',
            observer: 'disableReference'
        }

        computeDataAvailability: function (data) {
            return Object.keys(data).length === 0;
        }

        disableReference: function (dataNotLoaded) {
            if (!dataNotLoaded) {
                this.$.office_document.ref.off();
            }
        },
```

I prefer this approach because it allows me to use Polymerfire and I needed to check if the data were loaded to disable paper-spinner so it didn't cause unnecessary complexity in my code.